# Import external user to firebase

Tags: go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to import users from an external database to firebase.

The password were hashed with a `sha256` function with the password prepended by a salt (which is a UUID).

For example:

```
password = "123qwerty!"
salt = "cb60eb29-95a2-418e-be2a-c1c107fb1add"
hash = sha256(salt+password)
# 54ccb21d42c6961aa1b666b7cb0485f85aab2f2323399fb2959ea5e4e9f6f595
```

Now to import this to firebase I would do the following:

```golang
users = []*auth.UserToImport
users = append(users, (&auth.UserToImport{}).
    UID("some-uid").
    Email("jon.foo@example.com").
    PasswordHash([]byte("54ccb21d42c6961aa1b666b7cb0485f85aab2f2323399fb2959ea5e4e9f6f595")).
    PasswordSalt([]byte("cb60eb29-95a2-418e-be2a-c1c107fb1add")).
    DisplayName("Jon FOO"))

h := hash.SHA256{
    Rounds:     1,
    InputOrder: hash.InputOrderSaltFirst,
}
res, err := cl.ImportUsers(ctx, users, auth.WithHash(h))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The user is well imported in firebase (I can see it in the console), but when I try to login, I have this error `The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.`

I cannot see what is wrong with my way, maybe the `Rounds` parameter should be updated, but to what value?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to update my code to use nodejs as more example are made in this language and it could help me, and I'm suprised to see that there is no equivalent to the `InputOrder` in node.
So now I wonder if by default firebase would put the salt after the password and thus rejecting an error and I cannot specify this :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my issue.
In my case I was giving as the `PasswordHash` the hex representation of the password:

```golang
PasswordHash([]byte("54ccb21d42c6961aa1b666b7cb0485f85aab2f2323399fb2959ea5e4e9f6f595")).
```

It turns out I have to decode first the password, like the following:

```golang
decoded, err := hex.DecodeString("54ccb21d42c6961aa1b666b7cb0485f85aab2f2323399fb2959ea5e4e9f6f595")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
user := (&auth.UserToImport{}).
    PasswordHash(decoded).
    PasswordSalt([]byte("cb60eb29-95a2-418e-be2a-c1c107fb1add")). // the salt stays the same
    ...

// call ImportUsers with the same hash configuration (Rounds: 1, InputOrder: SaltFirst)
```

After updating this I ran the code and I could now authenticate with my imported user.

Quick note: as mentionned in the comment, the node SDK does not have the option to specify the input order (salt or password first), this seems to be an important missing feature.